# domsanitizer give safe html content but anchor tag not clickable after sanitization

Tags: angular6, sanitization, angular-dom-sanitizer

I'm using `DomSanitizer` in angular 6. I want to sanitize my content which contains `iframes` hyperlinks videos content etc. After sanitization I'm getting all the content its just anchor tags are not clickable now. Kindly help me with this.

I've tried something like this too

```
this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(myContent));

        content: "<p>کراچی (مانیٹرنگ ڈیسک )متحدہ قومی موومنٹ نے عمرا ن فاروق قتل کیس میں ملوث ملزمان سے لا تعلقی کا اظہار کردیا ۔ایم کیو ایم کی جانب سے جاری اعلامیے میں کہا گیا ہے کہ عمران فاروق کئی سال سے ہمارے دیرینہ دوست تھے ،ایم کیو ایم کے کسی کارکن کاعمران فاروق کی موت سے تعلق نہیں ۔نجی نیوز چینل جیونیوز کے مطابق ایم کیو ایم کا کہنا ہے کہ عمران فاروق قتل کیس میں زیر حراست افراد کے مبینہ اعتراف کی اطلاعات سے آگاہ ہیں ،ان افراد نے مبینہ طور پر قتل کے احکامات کے لیے ایم کیو ایم کی شخصیات کے نام لیے ہیں ۔ایم کیو ایم دوست اور ساتھی کی موت پر غمزدہ ہے اورہم برطانیہ کی میٹرو پولیٹن پولیس کو ہر تعاون فراہم کرنے کے لیے تیار ہیں ۔</p>
    ↵ 
    ↵<p><a href="https://fb.com/demo12/08-Jan-2016/317638" title="سعودی ایران کشیدگی ، ایران سے جنگ کی صورتحال کی کسی صورت اجازت نہیں دیں گے : سعودی نائب ولی عہد">سعودی ایران کشیدگی ، ایران سے جنگ کی صورتحال کی کسی صورت اجازت نہیں دیں گے : سعودی نائب ولی عہد</a></p>
    ↵ 
    ↵<p><a href="https://publishrr.com">https://publishrr.com</a></p>
    ↵ 
    ↵<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
    ↵<tbody>
    ↵<tr style="height: 23px;">
    ↵<td style="width: 25%; height: 23px;">3</td>
    ↵<td style="width: 25%; height: 23px;">2</td>
    ↵<td style="width: 25%; height: 23px;">2</td>
    ↵<td style="width: 25%; height: 23px;">1</td>
    ↵</tr>
    ↵<tr style="height: 23px;">
    ↵<td style="width: 25%; height: 23px;">3</td>
    ↵<td style="width: 25%; height: 23px;">3</td>
    ↵<td style="width: 25%; height: 23px;">3</td>
    ↵<td style="width: 25%; height: 23px;">4</td>
    ↵</tr>
    ↵<tr style="height: 23px;">
    ↵<td style="width: 25%; height: 23px;">sa</td>
    ↵<td style="width: 25%; height: 23px;">ds</td>
    ↵<td style="width: 25%; height: 23px;">tg</td>
    ↵<td style="width: 25%; height: 23px;">4</td>
    ↵</tr>
    ↵</tbody>
    ↵</table>";

    senitizeHtml(content) {
        return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
    }
    senitizeResourceURL(url) {
        return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
```

Anchor link in this content should be clickable.